# Is it possible to compose LINQ with raw SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

#### Question

The [official documentation shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq) that it's possible to start from raw SQL and then use the resulting `IQueryable<T>` with LINQ.

Is it possible to do the opposite? That is, given an `IQueryable<T>`, decorate that "view" with raw SQL?

---

#### What I've tried

I've tried to do:

```
IQueryable<T> query = ...;
var result = query.FromSql($"SELECT __result__.*, ... AS row_code FROM ({query.ToSql()}) AS __result__ WHERE ...");
```

The problem is that given a complex query it seems that `IQueryable<T>.FromSql` expects exactly the same table aliases as the original `query`. So for example if the original table alias is `'x'.*` then, given that we are creating a new `__result__` alias, EF core complains that there doesn't exist a `x.column_name` in the resulting query.

---

#### Example use case

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is to decorate the resulting `IQueryable` with a calculated row number (the row number relative to some other grouping) using user variables and then selecting only certain row numbers.

Comment: Hi, try to do this:  var result = from a in Context.tableName
             join h in Context.tableName2 on a.id equals h.id
             join c in Context.tableName3 on a.id3 equals c.id3
             where  "what you want"
             select new {
                 "your code here" };

Comment: @mrsWhite I can't use LINQ-to-SQL because it doesn't support user variables, which is what I'm trying to use.

Comment: You can run raw SQL from a DbSet, or from Database within EF, if that is applicable let me know and I can provide an answer

Comment: @andyb952 It's not applicable. I know you can do that, I've provided a link to the documentation that explains that. I'm trying to embed an `IQueryable<T>` into a raw SQL query not viceversa.

Comment: The obvious question is why can't you use the same table aliases? Presumably the correct table aliases are essential to EF for mapping to property names.

Comment: @TimRogers Because they conflict with the inner `query.ToSql()` which has the same aliases.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Looking at your previous question, you may find interesting this [blog post](https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore/_wiki/wikis/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.wiki?pagePath=%2FFeatures%2FRowNumber%20Support&pageId=14&wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster) and supporting source code for adding [ROW_NUMBER](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) support which can be used to solve top N per group problem. The code is for SqlServer, you have to adjust it for MySQL.